# Select rows based on MAX values of a column in ScalaQuery/SLICK

Tags: scala, subquery, max, scalaquery, slick

Say that i have table such as:

```
UserActions
    UserId INT
    ActionDate TIMESTAMP
    Description TEXT
```

that holds dates where users perfomed certainActions.  If i wanted to get the last action that every user perfomed, i would have to do something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   UserActions,
       (
           SELECT ua.UserId,
                  max(ua.ActionDate) AS lastActionDate
           FROM   UserActions ua
           GROUP BY ua.UserId
       ) AS lastActionDateWithUserId
WHERE  UserActions.UserId = lastActionDateWithUserId.UserId 
  AND  UserActions.ActionDate = lastActionDateWithUserId.lastActionDate
```

Now, assume that i already have a table structure set up in scalaquery 0.9.5 for the UserActions such as:

```
case class UserAction(userId:Int,actionDate:Timestamp,description:String)

object UserActions extends BasicTable[UserAction]("UserActions"){

    def userId = column[Int]("UserId")

    def actionDate = column[Timestamp]("ActionDate")

    def description  = column[String]("Description")

    def * = userId ~ actionDate ~ description <> (UserAction, UserAction.unapply _)
}
```

My question is: in ScalaQuery/SLICK how can i perform such a query?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used Slick 1.0.0 with Scala 2.10.

I defined the objects like this:

```
case class UserAction(userId: Int, actionDate: Timestamp, description: String)

object UserActions extends Table[UserAction]("UserActions") {

  def userId = column[Int]("UserId")
  def actionDate = column[Timestamp]("ActionDate")
  def description = column[String]("Description")
  def * = userId ~ actionDate ~ description <> (UserAction, UserAction.unapply _)
}
```

Within session block

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {
  //...
}
```

I inserted some sample data

```
UserActions.insert(UserAction(10, timeStamp, "Action 1"))
UserActions.insert(UserAction(10, timeStamp, "Action 2"))
UserActions.insert(UserAction(10, timeStamp, "Action 3"))
UserActions.insert(UserAction(20, timeStamp, "Action 1"))
UserActions.insert(UserAction(20, timeStamp, "Action 2"))
UserActions.insert(UserAction(30, timeStamp, "Action 1"))

Query(UserActions).list foreach println
```

First thing to do is create the max query

```
// group by userId and select the userId and the max of the actionDate
val maxQuery =
  UserActions
    .groupBy { _.userId }
    .map {
      case (userId, ua) =>
        userId -> ua.map(_.actionDate).max
    }
```

The resulting query looks like this

```
val result =
  for {
    ua <- UserActions
    m <- maxQuery
    if (ua.userId === m._1 && ua.actionDate === m._2)
  } yield ua

result.list foreach println
```